# Why translation in liferay doesn't work - asset publisher

Tags: liferay, translation

I start to use Asset Publisher in liferay. I added an article with some text in english. Then I want to add translation but there was no my language. So I added into portal-ext.properties next lines to enable more languages.

```
locales.enabled=ca_ES,zh_CN,en_US,fi_FI,fr_FR,de_DE,iw_IL,hu_HU,ja_JP,pt_BR,es_ES,cs_CZ,sk_SK
```

My language then appear, but the problem is the translation doesn't work. Not to my language, it doesn't work to any other languages. All it did is it just changed the font of the text. That's all. Can you help me and tell me what should I do? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can it be because the virtual host name is set as localhost?

Comment: this conversation began on https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/48426200. Should we continue there?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be solved on the [Liferay forums](https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/48426200): You'll need to provide the translation yourself. Liferay offers the functionality to enter translated articles, but it doesn't translate the articles itself.

If I may add a personal remark: "...luckily". Automatic translation is not that good.